# Work in other EU countries while I have temporary Residence permit in Lithuania

Tags: job-search, visa, europe

I am iOS Developer and co-founder of a startup in Lithuania and as non-EU citizen I have startup visa and temporary residence permit in Lithuania.
Do I have permission to looking for job in other EU countries like Netherland? 
Can I apply for residency in that country?
What is the rules for looking for a job in another country if I am already in EU?

Comment: You need to ask an actual lawyer.

Comment: Someone else can find the proof. But, the answer will be **no**. There is no link here. Your residency in one country is irrelevant to the others.

Comment: Welcome new user - for this question you should ask on the SE expatriates site - this is the wrong site!  Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This is a serious matter, you need to know the OFFICIAL requirements, which depend among other things on your citizenship.

NEVER RELY ON NON GOVERNMENTAL INFORMATION SOURCES !

**Always contact the respective authorities with immigration questions.**

Please look at the official website of the country you'd like to work / live in as well as the website of your embassy in that country.

If in doubt contact the official hotlines for these matters or seek legal advice.

Comment: I got to review this post as Low Quality Post. Frankly, I see absolutely nothing wrong with it. The advice (if I am not mistaken) is: please contact the authorities. And this is a perfect answer. To the user who raised the flag, please explain why this is not an answer.

Comment: @scaahu well put, thank you. I added it to my answer to make my point very clear (;

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it

While EU citizens have freedom of movement rights to work anywhere in the EU and spouses of EU citizens have freedom of movement rights to work in any EU country other than the EU spouses own country<sup>1</sup> the rules for non-EU citizens in general working in the EU have not been harmonized and are still a matter for each individual country.

If you would otherwise have needed a Visa to visit Schengen countries<sup>2</sup> then your residence permit from a Schengen country lets you visit other Schengen countries but it doesn't let you work or reside there.

I don't think there is anything that would stop you from looking at jobs while visiting, but to actually take the job you would need suitable authorization to work. So most likely you will be limited to jobs that are willing and able to sponsor non-EU workers.

<sup>1</sup> Yes, crazy as it is spouses of EU citizens can have more rights in other EU countries than the EU spouses home country.

<sup>2</sup> Most Schengen countries are in the EU and most EU countries are in the Schengen area, but there are exceptions in both directions.